# Is it valid for the model to call a method that updates the view in MVP?

Tags: mvp

I have a very simple question.  Someone else might have this question as well but is not asking it.  So I will.

My question is: Is it valid, in the MVP model, to have the model call a method that updates the view?

Or do I have to have the model call the method and the method gets the data for the model, then the model passes that information to the presenter and the presenter sends the data to the view.

Thanks,

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One goal of the MVP pattern is to separate the view from the model. Model, View and Presenter have distinct responsibilities.

For an effective MVP implementation, you should call a method on the presenter if your data has changed. Updating the view is the job of the presenter.

Comment: I see.  So then would it be okay if the model called a method that gave information to the presenter, which in turn updated the view?

Comment: Yes, that would be better. The model should only interact with the presenter. I prefer a solution where the presenter subscribes to changes on the model, i.e. the model offers an event which is fired whenever a property on the model is changed. MVP is not a strict pattern which has only one correct implementation. MVP is a concept which highlights several ideas to create a good design when using data in views.

Comment: Yes, I have seen some different ways to implement the MVP model.  But thank you for your answer. :)